# Un-able to clone AWS-Code Commit Repo through Git-bsh from locl machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

Am new to AWS Code Commit concept, Creted  new Repo in aws code-commit, coppied the https url & tried to clone the repo from my locala machine using git clone [url]

there its throwing me the error: **fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/test/': The requested URL returned error: 403**

can any one please help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mX7o.png)

Comment: Have you setup your credentails as shown in [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275018/un-able-to-clone-aws-code-commit-repo-through-git-bsh-from-locl-machine) for CodeCommit access?

Comment: While it is worth correcting the issue you have, longer-term I'd recommend using SSH rather than HTTPS.